# How to import vForm globally in index.js using Vue js 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, javascript-framework

I want to register vForm in index.js globally in **Vue js 3** but not work, while using vuejs 2 it work like Vue.component(Form) in Vue **Vue js 3**  how to define once and usable in all window or component, this bellow code not working. Thanks for your comment and soon response.

```
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform';
app.use(Form);
app.use(HasError);
app.use(AlertError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works the same in Vue 3 - but instead of using the global `Vue` you use your `app`:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router'; 
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform';

const myApp = createApp(App);
myApp.use(router);
myApp.component('v-form', Form);
myApp.component('has-error', HasError);
myApp.component('alert-error', AlertError);
myApp.mount('#app');
```

Comment: I got error as the bellow code.    warning  in ./src/main.js

export 'HasError' (imported as 'HasError') was not found in 'vform' (possible exports: Errors, Form, default)

 warning  in ./src/main.js

export 'AlertError' (imported as 'AlertError') was not found in 'vform' (possible exports: Errors, Form, default)

Comment: And now what? The error message is pretty clear - how do you plan to resolve it?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this finally?

Comment: Check whether your `vform` package actually exports a `HasError` component.

Answer (score 0):

This what i will do in `Vue 3`

```js
import App from "@/components/App";
import Form from "vform";
import { HasError, AlertError } from "vform/src/components/bootstrap5";
```

`HasError` and `AlertError` can also be imported from `vform/src/components/bootstrap4`

```js
const app = createApp(App);
window.Form = Form;
app.component("has-error", HasError);
app.component("alert-error", AlertError);
```